# How to return multiple elements from collection?

Tags: java, kotlin

In the list I need to replace each element with the sum of this element and all previous ones. The first element is not required to change.
Example: The list (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0) must be converted (1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 10.0). I'm looking for the most concise and correct way.

I was googling for a long time and could not find any useful information regarding the conversion of an element by the sum of its previous ones. Also I could not find the required function in the standard library at Kotlinlang.org. Please help solve this problem.

```
fun accumulate(list: MutableList<Double>): MutableList<Double> {
    if (list.isEmpty()) return list
    else for (i in 0 until list.size) {
        if (i == list.indexOf(list.first())) list[i] = list.first()
        else list[i] = list.sumByDouble { it } // here's my problem
    }
    return list
}
```

Comment: I find it very confusing to mutate the given list and return it too. A more idiomatic design would be to take a (immutable) List as argument and return a new (immutable) list, or at least to take a mutable list, mutate it, and return nothing.

Comment: Thank you! I will remember for the future.

Comment: `list.indexOf(list.first())` is likely 0 :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a variable that stores the running sum.

```
fun accumulate(list: MutableList<Double>): MutableList<Double> {
    var runningSum = 0.0
    list.indices.forEach { i ->
        runningSum += list[i]
        list[i] = runningSum
    }
    return list
}
```

Note that an empty list is not a special case for this code.

If you'd prefer to do it the FP way and non-destructively transform the list, you can write this:

```
fun accumulate(list: List<Double>): List<Double> {
    var runningSum = 0.0
    return list.map {
        runningSum += it
        runningSum
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write this simpler, by using `slice()` and `sum()`:

```
fun accumulate(list: MutableList<Double>) = list.mapIndexed { index, d -> list.slice(0..index).sum() }.toMutableList()
```

Comment: This is an O(n^2) solution to an O(n) problem.

Comment: I guess it is, but it is also just a simple way to solve the problem. Efficiency is something that OP has to decide about.

Comment: While you could stand a chance at invoking the "premature optimization" argument and pleading not to worry about fixed costs, It is _always_ wrong to write solutions with a gratuitously worse big-O complexity. Improvements in asymptotic complexity do not fit under the label of "optimization", but "performance debugging".

Comment: This is not less efficient that the OP's code, it is just simpler and not wrong.

Comment: It is simpler, semantically correct, and has the same complexity bug as OP's.